# How to send a message to only one attendee in a Google Meet?

Tags: google-meet

When participating to a Google Meet video meeting you can send a message in the chat to all attendees.

How to send a message only to a specific attendee?

I tried to type `@` followed by the name but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Meet doesn't include a feature to privately chat with a meeting participant. In the "Google web app universe" you could use Google Chat or Google Hangouts for that.

Comment: Ok thanks I wasn't sure about it.